# Upgrading to MacOS from 10.6.8 MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

I have 2011 MacBook Pro that I have not used for a while. Now I am back to using it and would like to upgrade to the latest OS available. Currently, it is 10.6.8 an here are the issues

1. When I try to download the MacOS High Sierra from the App store, the "Get" button is grey and nothing happens when I click it. In fact, all the apps are like this and I cannot use the App store to download anything at all (I have signed it with my Apple ID).
2. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at the booting is not working so I cannot even restore to factory settings.
3. I do not have recovery disks.

Could you please help me to sort this out as I am not familiar with Mac that much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos)

Comment: You may need to go via Lion to Mavericks to Yosemite to get to where you want to be... Exact steps I have not checked, but that may be why the button is greyed out...

Comment: Get the latest updates, then the store button works.

Comment: @pepper_chico How can I get the latest updates?

Comment: @abd I did it in System Settings, there's a update icon there.

Answer (score 1):

## Are you using a 32-bit machine?

Unfortunately, 32-bit systems cannot run any OS after Snow Leopard (10.6). You have a few options:

- Keep using Snow Leopard (be **extremely careful about security**, as I don't think it's still receiving updates)
- Buy a newer Mac (possibly used)
- Install [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/desktop) and use it instead of OS X

If your machine is 64-bit, then I don't know what the problem is.